# Remote Audio Stream not routed to bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, webrtc, avaudiosession

I have application which has video call functionality using webRTC. If bluetooth is connected then audio should be routed to bluetooth headset. I am using following code.

```
func configAudioSession()
    {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        var _: Error?
        try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: [ .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])

        try? session.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)

        try? session.setActive(true)

    }
```

Using above code if i play .mp3 file from application bundle, then it routs audio stream correctly to bluetooth speaker when connected.But it is not working webRTC remote audio stream.With remote stream there is no audio in bluetooth headset. How can i resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the answer?